# Firebase: What signatures should be present in Settings?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

In Firebase, whenever I try to write to Firestore I'm getting permission errors in flutter. So I wanted to ask what signatures are you supposed to put in the settings? I'm currently using the services Firestore, Auth, and AppCheck.

I have 6 signatures in my settings:

- **SHA-1, SHA-256:** debug.keystore
- **SHA-1, SHA-256:** upload-keystore (is this needed?)
- **SHA-1, SHA-256:** App signing key certificate from google console

The reason why I think it has something to do with the signatures is because I'm able to write to Firestore when I'm using `AndroidProvider.debug` in AppCheck. But when I make my release version using `AndroidProvider.playIntegrity` Firestore denies me.

Error:

```
E/flutter (25396): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

Firestore rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isDev();
    }
    
    function isAuth() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    
    function isDev() {
      let datalist = ['myemail@foo.com'];
      return isAuth() && request.auth.token.email in datalist;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint that you can find in *App integrity > App signing key certificate* on the *Google Play Console*.

I stumbled upon the same issue today, and this is my current working setup. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I already am as stated in the post.

Comment: could it be that my release mode is using the wrong keys? If ever how do I check this?

Comment: Do you initialize Firestore with the correct AndroidProvider according to the build type, like : kDebugMode ? AndroidProvider.debug : AndroidProvider.playIntegrity ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I'm _really_ considering [creating a new key](https://shorturl.at/jlAMY) as a last resort. Although I'm still inclined to know if my _upload-keystore.jks_ really is being used since working with `AndroidProvider.debug` is fine but `AndroidProvider.playIntegrity` is not. @Valentin could it be I got my password wrong in my _key.properties_ file? That would be such a [noob](https://shorturl.at/ahBK0) thing to do but if ever I did get the password wrong shouldn't the release build fail?

Comment: Have you also tried to make the Firestore rules really loose? Like temporarily allowing all reads and writes with an `if true` statement? (and perhaps combined with a timestamp check, to make the statement obsolete after you're done with testing). This would be to make sure that the error doesn't come from your rule logic and remove this hypothesis from the problem.

Comment: EDIT : sorry, my above comment might not make sense as you said that debug mode doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Valentin not a problem, I'm just happy I could have a convo on this as it's driving me nuts. Still getting the same firestore perm restrictions after setting it to `allow read: if true;`. After giving it some thought, since I already have the proper signatures in my project settings, the problem must then lie in my upload-keystore. I swear I'd give anything just to see a different error message for a change. :p

Comment: EDIT: This is how I create my bundle: `flutter clean && flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols/`. The use of `--release` is default so I don't add it anymore. But anyway, once my latest release passes review (or fails) and it still won't work then I'll be sure to include it explicitly this time. I'll let you know.

Comment: Ah, maybe try pushing your app bundle to an internal track on the Play Console and test with an instance of your app downloaded through Google Play.
Testing on a locally built release version of my app didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah good idea. I've been releasing to alpha in closed testing. I'll try making a release to internal testing. If this doesn't work I'll try it on open testing.

Comment: Do you have either of these in your app/build.gradle dependencies: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'` or `implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.0.2'`?

Comment: UPDATE: Funny thing is that I'm able to get appcheck to run in API 12 but not in API 9. Right now I don't have a device that uses 10, 11 so I can't say for those two. Still testing on why it won't run in 9. My `minSdkVersion` is 26.

Answer (score 0):

Okay long story short, I found out the phone I was testing API 28 on had been previously rooted. The original ROM had eventually been reinstalled but I guess it still qualifies as being rooted according to AppCheck.